# Sound card works with ALSA, but not showing in volume mixer

Tags: linux, debian, sound-card, alsa, pulse-audio

After a system upgrade I noticed I had no sound. In the volume mixer I see that my integrated sound card is not shown, while another one (HDMI) is.

I managed to find that the device name is `CARD=MID` using `aplay -L` and I can indeed hear sound when I perform this:

```
$ for dev in `aplay -L | grep "CARD=MID"`; do aplay -D $dev /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav 2> /dev/null && echo $dev; done
default:CARD=MID
sysdefault:CARD=MID
```

I can also hear sound with `speaker-test`, without any arguments.

In `alsamixer` the card is as well shown, it appears as the default one (`HDA Intel MID`), and I can adjust the volume from there when I play sound with `aplay` or `speaker-test`.

In order to get the sound card work in the system, I stopped pulseaudio and removed the local configuration files at `~/.config/pulse/`, but nothing changed on restart.

I think that the system upgrade could have left some sound configuration in a broken state, but I don't know where to look into.

**Edit:**

I attach the output of `lsof -n /dev/snd/*` in some situations.

With pulseaudio stopped:

```
$ lsof -n /dev/snd/*
$
```

with pulseaudio running:

```
$ lsof -n /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
pulseaudi 3463 etuardu   16u   CHR 116,14      0t0 13058 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi 3463 etuardu   23u   CHR 116,14      0t0 13058 /dev/snd/controlC1
$
```

while playing sound with speaker-test:

```
$ lsof -n /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
pulseaudi 3463 etuardu   16u   CHR 116,14      0t0 13058 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi 3463 etuardu   23u   CHR 116,14      0t0 13058 /dev/snd/controlC1
speaker-t 3481 etuardu  mem    CHR  116,2          13523 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
speaker-t 3481 etuardu    3r   CHR 116,33      0t0  2850 /dev/snd/timer
speaker-t 3481 etuardu    4u   CHR  116,2      0t0 13523 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
speaker-t 3481 etuardu    5u   CHR  116,5      0t0 11209 /dev/snd/controlC0
$
```

Comment: "_volume mixer_" means `alsamixer` or `pavucontrol`?

Comment: I meant the gui volume mixer of my desktop environment (gnome control center / audio). I installed `pavucontrol` and the card is not shown there neither. On the other hand it is visible and working in `alsamixer`.

Comment: Then it seems to be a `pulseaudio` bug, or some application take your soundcard when pulseaudio starts, so it cannot bind to it. Try restarting pulseaudio with `-v -v -v` parameters to see what's going on. (update your question with this output)

Comment: This is the output of `pulseaudio -v -v -v` when started: https://pastebin.com/raw/jjCdB3iN

Comment: `D: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0 is busy: yes`, so one app is already using your soundcard.

Comment: Try `lsof -n /dev/snd/*` to find out which.

Comment: I edited the question to add its output

Comment: I don't know what is `speaker-t` with pid `3481`, but kill it, and remove it from autostart.

Comment: Or remove it completely: `dpkg --remove $(dpkg -S \`realpath /proc/3481/exe\`)`

Comment: It is `speaker-test`, I run it on purpose in order to test the speakers (similar to `aplay`, it plays pink noise) and killed it afterwards. It seems to use `/dev/snd/controlC0`. Even when the device is not used according to `lsof`, for some reasons pulseaudio does not handle it when I restart it